# Does memory mapping files interfere with memory management?

Tags: android, nio, bytebuffer, mappedbytebuffer

I wrote an app that uses a memory mapping to access file.  Read speed increased dramatically, so it was a success.

As expected, the memory allocated for the `ByteBuffer` is not counted against the VM heap.  In a heap dump, it appears that my app uses significantly less memory than it actually does.

My question is, **what effect (if any) does this kind of allocation have on the device's memory management as it pertains to other apps?**  Does it make my app a "bad citizen" of the Android ecosystem?

Comment: It all depends how much memory you're mapping. All resources have to come from somewhere. Last time I measured memory mapping speed it was only 20% faster than other techniques. Maybe your measurements aren't accurate?

Comment: @EJP Around 25 MB.  Memory mapping cut the read time from 10 seconds to around 2 seconds.  (Other similar apps also load the same file in around 10 seconds, so my original implementation wasn't particularly slow.)

Comment: That's remarkable. Was the 10 second implementation buffered?